# Supertest - do I need request(app)?

Tags: mocha.js, supertest, web-api-testing

I am looking at using Supertest for API tests. The API exists on Heroku. The example of the test given by the developers is:

```
    var assert = require("chai").assert;
    var request   = require("supertest");
    var server = require("../myapp");

    it("should return the correct HTML", function (done) {
    var app = server();
        **request(app)**
        .get("/")
        .end(function (err, res) {
        assert.isTrue(res.text.indexOf("</html>") > 0);
        done();
    });
});
```

My questions:
 1. Do I need app to make this work? If not, how can I simply send CRUD calls to my API?
 2. How can I get back values from promises so that I can pass them to another Supertest call?

I know how to do this using https-as-promise but it gets pretty messy.

Thanks
Jason